# Misplaced link click areas in Android Mobile Chrome

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I am having some troubles with links on Android Mobile Chrome.
Click area for the link is misplaced, but only in Mobile Chrome browsers. Everywhere else it's working flawlessly. You can see here on image, blue rectangle is the click area in Chrome:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Custom font** is the problem, I had the same issue on my app/mobile site. Try disabling it and your link clickable areas will magically come back to the proper location.

Comment: My bad, it was a coincidence: in my case it was the container <div> with **height** set to 100% that caused the problem. Leaving **no height value specified**... fixed it. Even using px values gave me the visual bug.